# Is there anyway to customize the --reject-with answer in the iptables?

Tags: iptables

Is there any way to customize the answers that can be given with the `--reject-with` option of the REJECT of IPTABLES?
I was reading in the man of the IPTABLES the part of the REJECT and the only possible answers are:

```
  --reject-with type
               Type can be
               -icmp-net-unreachable
               -icmp-host-unreachable
               -icmp-port-unreachable
               -icmp-proto-unreachable
               -icmp-net-prohibited
               -icmp-host-prohibited
               -icmp-admin-prohibited
```

I would like to know if it is possible to change any of them or show a customized response by me.

Comment: These are all the established messages for delivery problems. Could you be more specific what kind of non-standard response you want to send?

Comment: 332/5000
Hi @SteffenUllrich , thanks for your answer.
I would like to put a customized message for me ... the first one that comes to my mind would be something like:
"YOU CAN NOT PING ME!!!"

I have been searching the net for quite some time, but I have not been able to find any answers.

Is there any way to do this ?!

Salu2

PS: Sorry for my English.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Do you want a custom ICMP message which gets dropped by the peer anyway because its not a standard ICMP message or do you want some application level response (which needs an established connection first for TCP) or what exactly do you want to block (i.e. which protocol) and how exactly to respond?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thanks for the answer, again.  I just want that when someone tries to ping my PC, the answer you get is "Message customized by me" (ie YOU CAN NOT PING !!!) instead of Destination Host Unreachable or any of the standard offered by the REJECT option IPTABLES. I don't want some application!!! Do you understand now?

Comment: I know it's not a standard thing that I want to do...but I like know if is even posible...thxs

Comment: when someone pings you (i.e. ICMP echo request) then you either can send some ICMP error back (i.e. reject) or respond with an ICMP echo response. Only this one can take any payload but this payload will be thrown away by the peer anyway without looking at it. Any other packets you send back will be thrown away also by the peer because they are not an accepted response to a ICMP echo request. So you might create your own answer to the ICMP echo request with some iptables extension (you need to write) or with raw sockets but the peer will throw it away in all cases without looking at it.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich thxs for the answer. I'll continue searching  but hopeless because your answers... :(   Thxs anyway